# Python Socket programming: Post sentence - Info not reaching to web server?

Tags: python, sockets

So i got to the web-server and i can display the info with the next code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import socket
import sys

HOST = 'www.inf.utfsm.cl'
GET = '/~mvaras/tarea1.php'
UA = 'tarea1'
PORT = 80

try:
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
  sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])
  sys.exit(1)

try:
  sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error, msg:
  sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])
  sys.exit(2)

sock.send("GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\nUser-Agent: %s\r\n\r\n" % (GET, HOST, UA))
sock.send("POST Alexis Ahumada 17536441-2HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\nUser-Agent: tarea1\r\n\r\n")


data = sock.recv(1024)
string = ""
while len(data):
  string = string + data
  data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print string

sys.exit(0)
```

but the thing is the info i send (Alexis Ahumada 17536441-2) never writes on the server log (www.inf.utfsm.cl/~mvaras/tarea1.log) i'd want to know what i'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated i've really looked everywhere by now :(

Comment: `'http://www.inf.utfsm.cl/~mvaras/tarea1.php'` is not an IP address or host name. Sockets connect to hosts, not URLs...

Comment: thing is i need to use sockets and when i ping the url i have no response at all

Comment: You can't ping a URL, as @twalberg already implicitly explained. Effectively, you can only ping an IP address, while the ping utility program will also try to resolve a hostname for your convenience. An HTTP URL is not a hostname though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
TCP_IP = ('http://www.inf.utfsm.cl/~mvaras/tarea1.php')
```

to

```
TCP_IP = 'www.inf.utfsm.cl'
```

and then you will need send a HTTP request for "~mvaras/tarea1.php"

The trouble is that you are trying to communicate in the HTTP protocol over a TCP connection - HTTP is a much higher level protocol.

instead of using `socket` you need to use the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for this.

Comment: are you sure that will cause this issue? they are equivalent.

Comment: the first is not an address but a URI

Comment: for the request library do i need to change the socket method? the point is kinda to do a get and post to that url using sockets, as you can note i'm real noob on python and networks, i know that i need an ip for the connection but the context of the homework is to not use urllib but import sockets, i really appreciate your help though :)

Comment: The parens are indeed superfluous. When changing that, also change the name of the constant, it should rather be `HOST` or somesuch. Concerning the use of the request library, please check out the link that scytale provided to get an overview.